# Can I shoehorn a DateTimePicker date and a Textbox "Time" into a DateTime?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, wpf-controls

I have a group of components like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Label>Between</Label>
    <DatePicker Name="dtpFrom" ></DatePicker>
    <TextBox Name="timeFrom" MinWidth="60" />
    <Label>and</Label>
    <DatePicker Name="dtpTo"></DatePicker>
    <TextBox Name="timeTo"
               MinWidth="60" />
</StackPanel>
```

where the user can select the date and set the "From" date and time and the "To" date and time.

I want to combine these (the date portion of the DatePicker with the corresponding time portion represented within the TextBox) into a DateTime value. e.g., with:

```
DateTime dtFrom;
```

...I want to be able to do something like (pseudocode):

```
dtFrom = (DateTime) dtpFrom.Date + Convert.ToTime(timeFrom);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: BTW, the time values are like "11:03:49" (or "23:03:49" for PM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend handling this within your DataContext (ie: ViewModel), and binding to two separate properties.  These could easily map to an underlying `DateTime`.

For example:

```
// In ViewModel
private DateTime dateTime;

public DateTime Date
{
    get { return dateTime.Date; }
    set
    {
        if (value != dateTime.Date)
        {
            dateTime = value.Date + dateTime.TimeOfDay;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }
}

public TimeSpan Time
{
    get { return dateTime.TimeOfDay; }
    set
    {
        if (value != dateTime.TimeOfDay)
        {
            dateTime = dateTime.Date + value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Time");
        }
    }
}
```

This would let you bind each control to the appropriate property, but still maintain everything within a single `DateTime` instance.